# Filtering list results by date (or other model params)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model:

```
class Call(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    send_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    ...
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, null=True, blank=True)
```

And a corresponding ModelSerializer:

```
class CallSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='call-detail',
    )
    recipient = PhoneNumberField(read_only=False)
    status = SurveySerializer(source='survey', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Call
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'send_on', ...)
        lookup_field= 'pk'
```

And view:

```
class CallList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CallSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrSuperuser,)

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the calls
        for the currently authenticated user.
        """
        ...
```

I want to be able to support API list requests that let the caller get `Call`s filtered by date ranges for `send_on`. I am not sure how to do this in a RESTful way and what way it is meant to be done by DRF, but something like this:

```
mydomain.com/call/?start=2013-11-25T12:50:17&end=2013-11-28T12:50:17
```

And the return would list all calls with `send_on` between the given dates. What's the correct way to implement this with DRF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's clearly explained in the DRF docs [here](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering#filtering-against-query-parameters).

So in your case it would look like:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

class CallList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    # ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        filter = {}
        queryset = Call.objects.all()

        start_date = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('start_date', None)
        end_date = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('end_date', None)

        if start_date is not None:
            filter['send_on__gte'] = parse(start_date)

        if end_date is not None:
            filter['send_on__lte'] = parse(end_date)

        queryset = queryset.filter(**filter)

        return queryset
```

I use [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) to easily parse the iso formatted datetime.

Comment: Doh! Missed this in the docs, thanks. Was great to see this coded in nice style though. BTW, is there a way to document such filter params so that users know about it in the browseable API?